# How do I change the query so that it inserts only some amount of rows and then deletes them?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I've got a query:

```
INSERT INTO rates (name, value, time) 
SELECT name, value, now()
FROM updated_rates
ON CONFLICT (name) DO UPDATE
SET value = excluded.value, time = excluded.time;
```

How do I change the query so that I can select and insert only some number of rows(first 10 or 100, for example) and then delete these rows? There are other columns in the table as well

Comment: You can't do that in a single query. You can limit the rows inserted with an `ORDER BY`  and a `LIMIT`. You would have to do a separate delete operation. To make this work will require some sort of process to track what items have been inserted and use that information to do the delete. An alternate solution would be to have a delete trigger on `updated_rates` that inserts the deleted records into `rates`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver if I only have to insert first 10 rows and then delete first 10 rows would something like: “delete from updated rates where row_number() < 10” work?

Comment: You are assuming nothing changed between the insert and the delete. In any case it would be `<= 10`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yeah, these two queries are “bundled” together, insert and then delete, otherwise I guess I’d have to store the inserted ids in another table and then delete by those ids

Comment: @Belayer, I’m sorry, I don’t really get what you’re trying to imply. I’m inserting from first table to the second one, then deleting these values from the first one

Comment: Sorry, I missed that they were different tables.